# App icon set has unassigned children (deleting, cleaning, and building still doesn't help).

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I built an app on Ionic 3, and attempted to upload the app to App Store Connect via Xcode. Before trying this, ten images in the Images.xcassets folder have a yellow triangle warning "The app icon set has unassigned children". I tried deleting these images, cleaning, and building, but then the App Store Connect upload gives me an error as well. Either way, whether or not the images are there, App Store Connect displays a list of errors.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please put errors in your question or screen short of your app icon assets

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to basically use a webpage called MakeAppIcon to generate the icons and a Contents.json. It works for iPhone apps, I'm not sure about iPad.